# Post on facebook user's wall on user make some interaction on website

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

There is a auction website in, the requirement is that everytime user make a bidding on an auction. That action will be posted on their facebook wall if the user allow us to post on their behalf. Is this possible to do and what i have to know to be able to do this. I don't know much about facebook application development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have knowledge of `facebook-c#-sdk` (as you tagged) but for this need to follow these steps

1. Authenticate user using [facebook OAuth 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) with [user_status](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) permission
2. and the you need to call status api with [required param](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/)

after googling I found a small solution to update status using facebook-c#-sdk

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);  
parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
    { "message", "this is my test message" }
};
fbClient.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is a possible solution, but a bit clunky.

Leveraging Open Graph Actions would be better.

Your starting point would bd to read:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

It's not quite as easy as FB suggest of course and the documentation is sketchy, but for an automated, 'frictionless' action as per your requirement, this is the route to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I created an video tutorial and sample source code for doing exactly this.

Video/Code:
http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Grant-Access-And-Post-As-Facebook-User-ASPNet

If you don't feel like going to my website, here is the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using Facebook;

namespace FBO
{
    public partial class facebooksync : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckAuthorization();
        }

        private void CheckAuthorization()
        {
            string app_id = "374961455917802";
            string app_secret = "9153b340ee604f7917fd57c7ab08b3fa";
            string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

            if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                    }
                }

                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

                client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "markhagan.me video tutorial" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```